# How in the world does this code block work [trees]?

Tags: c++, tree

How exactly does the below code block work? More specifically, **how does the program know which option to return?**

```
return    ancestor (node1->left(), node2)
           || ancestor (node1->right(), node2)
           || ancestor (node2->left(), node1)
           || ancestor (node2->left(), node1);
```

This code block is part of code to traverse a tree in order to determines if one node is an ancestor of the other one when given node1 and node2 in a tree.

Note that node1 and node2 are passed in to the function that is responsible for determining if there is a possible ancestor/descendent relationship:

```
bool ancestor (const Binary_node<Type> * node1, const Binary_node<Type> * node2)
{
         // .... code
}
```

Comment: What a lovely recursion you've got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the program know which option to return?

The program will keep trying the options, until it finds one that works.

> How exactly does the below code block work?

In each call to ancestor(), the function will try four possibilities:

- Move node1 to its left subtree, and try to work through the rest rest of the problem.
- If that didn't work, try to move node1 to its right subtree instead.
- If that didn't work, move node2 to its left subtree instead.
- If that didn't work, move node2 to its right subtree instead.

If all four possibilities failed, then nodes node1 and node2 are surely not related via ancestor relationship.

**Warning:** As implemented, the ancestor function is extremely slow, except for very small trees. Because we try four options in each ancestor() call, the number of states roughly quadruples if you increase the height of the tree by 1.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the calls to `ancestor` returns true, it will return true (without evaluating the rest of the calls).

Comment: but this is the code responsible for traversing the tree searching if node1 is ancestor of node2 or vice versa... how is it doing this via the aforementioned implementation... 0_o

Comment: There are probably some other places, where used functions return boolean value, aren't there?

Answer (score 2):

The terms are evaluated left to right and the first one that is `true` terminates the evaluation (the *shortcut* boolean evaluation) and `true` is returned. Otherwise the result is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It evaluates from left to right, so it tests `ancestor (node1->left(), node2)` first. Next, it looks at the bitwise operator `||` which basically says, "if the previous operation is false, then try this next one".

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your function returns a bool. If one of the ancestors is true, it will return true. If you use two boolean values, the outcome is the following:

```
A       B     (A  ||  B)
false  false    false
true   false    true
false  true     true
true   true     true
```

If you use several boolean values (or values, that can be interpreted as boolean), than `A||B||C..` is equal to `((A||B)||C)||...`

Answer (score 1):

It's returning a boolean value. So the block you are referring to just uses [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to return the first `true` value it finds, or `false` if they all evaluate as such.

Answer (score 1):

Where an statement has several clauses linked by || or && then the evaluation is from left to right, short circuiting at the first opportunity.  In this case as || is being used the function will work from left to right (or top to bottom in your code layout) and the first time something evaluates true it will return true, avoiding evaluating the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ancestor return only true/false. This code makes use of early logical expression evaluation. In 'or' (||) statement. if first call does not return true it invokes next one and so on until one of them returns true. In case none of them returns true, false is returned.

In this code: If I find out that node1->left() is ancestor of node2 I do not have to evaluate rest of the statement since I already know the answer.